# Meaning of "turtles were drawing" in this paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, word-in-context

The paragraph exists in this website:
http://news.discovery.com/animals/why-do-some-turtles-breathe-out-of-their-butt-140617.htm

> And yet, when scientists placed a small amount of food coloring in the
>   water near these turtles, they found that the turtles were drawing in
>   water from both ends (and sometimes just the hind end.)

Here is what I can understand:

> And yet, when scientists placed a small amount of food coloring in the
>    water near these turtles,

I think this means: Scientists put food in the water near turtles.

What is the meaning of **turtles were drawing**? I don't think that turtles can draw paintings on a paper!!

The word **hind** means back or behind is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your excerpt

> And yet, when scientists placed **a small amount of food coloring** in the water near these turtles, they found that the turtles were **drawing in water** from both ends (and sometimes just the hind end.)

The scientists coloured the water with **food colouring** (nontoxic and safe colouring) to be able to see where the water went (since water itself is colourless).  Usually red or blue is used to follow water movements.

To **draw** water is to **gather** or **collect** water

> He **drew** water from the nearby well.

The scientists found that water was used from both the front and back (hind) ends.

Comment: We could also mention to draw blood, not just water.